# Honda Accord Maintenance Minder accidental reset/ what to do now?

Tags: honda, maintenance, obd-ii, accord, dtc

I changed the oil on my 2015 Honda Accord LX myself for the first time. Following a YouTube video, I reset the Maintenance Minder. The problem is that I didn't note the extra codes that show up on the Maintenance Minder to perform that maintenance.

I'd like to find what those codes were.

Can I do this from the dash or with an OBDII scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never really checked but it wouldn't be anything you could do from generic obd2 you would need a scan tool that could talk to either the cluster computer or whatever other computer.

Check your service manual booklet it should tell you what needs to be checked/replaced based on mileage.